# How better organize grid lines?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

There are grid lines from points.

Is there another solution with better performance, because if I add many svg elements(etc. rects, circles, paths) and increase the dimension of the grid I will see the freeze effect when I use zoom, move element...

The size of the grid is changed.

Also, how can I create endless grid lines, instead limited (gridCountX, gridCountY)?

Thanks

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var svgG = svg.append("g");

var gridLines = svgG.append("g").classed("grid-lines-container", true).data(["gridLines"]);

var gridCountX = _.range(100);
var gridCountY = _.range(100);
var size = 10;

gridLines.selectAll("g").data(gridCountY)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).selectAll("circle").data(gridCountX).enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(_d) {return _d*size;})
            .attr("cy", function(_d) {return d*size;})
            .attr("r", 0.5)
            .attr("style", function() {
                return "stroke: black;";
            });
    });

var zoomSvg = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", function(){
            svgG.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        });
    
svg.call(zoomSvg);
```

```css
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your question asks about grid lines, but your example code is a collection of dots?

Comment: It's the grid lines(for ex. may be lines instead point). Therein lies the crux of the question: find a solution that will not affect the performance

Answer (score 1):

As you note, this approach is not really scalable and has a larger impact on performance. I have found the approach of utilizing d3 axes for grids to have minimal performance impact while also being relatively straightforward to incorporate with zoom such that you can have infinite zoom with the grid lines updating in a sensible manner due to the "magic" of automatic generation of sensible tick locations in d3.

To implement something similar in d3 v4, you can do something along these lines:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 140, bottom: 50, left: 70},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"),
    innerSvg = g.append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

// Calculate domain for x and y from data and store in x0, y0 (not shown here)
x.domain(x0);
y.domain(y0);

xGridAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10);
yGridAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10 * height / width); 


// Create grouping and additional set of axes for displaying grid
innerSvg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid x-grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate (0," + height + ")")
    .call(xGridAxis
              .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
              .tickFormat("")
    )
  .selectAll(".tick");

innerSvg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid y-grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate (" + width + ", 0)")
    .call(yGridAxis
              .tickSize(width)
              .tickFormat("")
    );

// Add element to capture mouse events for drag and pan of plots
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var scrollZoom = innerSvg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("pointer-events", "all") // Defaults to panning with mouse
    .call(zoom);

// Mouse panning and scroll-zoom implementation using d3.zoom
// Modification of : http://bl.ocks.org/lorenzopub/013c0c41f9ffab4d27f860127f79c5f5
function zoomed() {
  lastEventTransform = d3.event.transform;
  // Rescale the grid using the new transform associated with zoom/pan action
  svg.select(".x-grid").call(xGridAxis.scale(lastEventTransform.rescaleX(x)));
  svg.select(".y-grid").call(yGridAxis.scale(lastEventTransform.rescaleY(y)));

  // Calculate transformed x and y locations which are used to redraw all plot elements
  var xt = lastEventTransform.rescaleX(x),
      yt = lastEventTransform.rescaleY(y);

  // Code below just shows how you might do it. Will need to tweak based on your plot
  var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xt(d.x); })
      .y(function(d) { return yt(d.y); });

  innerSvg.selectAll(".line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

  innerSvg.selectAll(".dot")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {return xt(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {return yt(d.y); });
}
```

Here is a worked out example in d3 v4 that inspired my version above:

http://bl.ocks.org/lorenzopub/013c0c41f9ffab4d27f860127f79c5f5

Comment: Thanks for answer! It isn't clear example. Can I see a demonstration of working for solutions?

Comment: Also I use grid lines for calc size objects(rect, circle) and move ones, but not for a simple view lines.

Comment: How is it not a clear example? The bl.ocks.org link uses d3 v4 and clearly shows how to implement grids using d3 axes in a more scalable and efficient manner that also works with zooming/panning. Moreover, I stripped just the core logic in the code above so you can focus on the logic of how it works. You can modify for your own implementation, or alternately, fork the block which is a "working solution" and edit it to make it inline with whatever you are doing.